# Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file in fusionpbx

Tags: php, smarty, voip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I have installed fusionpbx in virtual server. I want to check provisioning module of FusionPBX. But when I am going to download files for any devices I am getting error like :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file //wrt583ff686d58cf9.75957020 <-- thrown in /var/www/fusionpbx/resources/templates/engine/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 45
```

Even I am confused that why it's going to write file on `'//file_path'` instead of `/tmp` folder.

Can anybody help me to sort out this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: how did you installed the fusion pbx with the help of installation script or manual installation?

Comment: I have installed it with script @suren

Answer (score 0):

The web server needs permission to write to the smarty template directory. Usually this is the /tmp directory. Also make sure you are running a current release if there was a bug its likely fixed now. If running on CentOS selinux could also prevent writing to the file system.

Comment: Hi Mark, can you provide generic path